# How storage affect if we use tertiary language?

Tags: computer-architecture, boolean-algebra, digital-circuits, storage

as we uses binary language in all the computer systems around us which consist of 0s and 1s (Off and On) bits. Let assume that someone is developing a computer system based on tertiary system -1, 0, 1 three states. The question is that how will it affect the storage of computer systems?

DUPLICATION: this question is different. Here the aspect is only of "storage"

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We've already got a bunch of questions here that discuss some of the implications of ternary systems.  Take a look at http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19084/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/27656/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/46998/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2040/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/39720/755.  If, after reading those, you have any question that you're still not sure about, feel free to edit your question here to ask a more specific question that's not already covered by one of those, and this can be considered for re-opening.

Comment: To be honest, at the moment I'm not seeing what you think is different.  The question http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19084/755 *is* talking about storage.  Perhaps it'd be clearer if this question was edited to be more focused and less open-ended. Can you edit the question to ask a more specific question?  What type/category of effects do you want to know?  What kinds of possible effects have you already considered or come up with?   "What is the effect of X on Y?" is a better question than "What are all the possible effects of X?" -- see our [help/dont-ask] for more.